# DNS - System Error when doing a ping

Tags: networking, dns

I'm working on Ubuntu Server (on VirtualBox) with Webmin and bind9 to create a DNS server. I've applied all I need and it works, but when powering on the server, I get a system error when doing a ping to the domain I've created.

However, if I go to Networking, Network Configuration, Hostname and DNS client within Webmin, make any fake modification (I deleted one DNS address and added it again) that makes webmin believe there was a change, save it and apply configuration, then the ping is working.

Looks like the right configuration is not being loaded at boot? If so, how can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: Well deleting and adding is making a change. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I’m using Ubuntu server 20.04 with webmin (latest version) and Ubuntu desktop. It’s for education purpose.

Comment: What is the exact system error?

Comment: All it says is "System error" when doing ping. 

ping www.example.com

and the output si

ping: www.example.com: System error